# what is the meaning of sub# in regexp_substr

Tags: sql, oracle

```
to_number(
     regexp_substr(cf.favorite_list, '[^,]+', 1, sub#)
  )
```

[image]

This is the result of the customer_favorites which means cf

Comment: Please show us the full query. Fourth argument should be occurance of matched pattern.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm), the fourth argument to `regexp_subsstr()` is the occurrence number.

The `sub#` would appear to be a column that specifies which value to take.  For instance, `1` would be the first substring in the string that matches the pattern; `2` would be the second.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. There was no explanation of this part.